# Subscribe Firing Twice on Option with Same Value

Tags: select, knockout.js, knockout-subscribe

I have an array that looks like this
[Name: toyota, Model: camry], [Name: toyota, Model: corolla]

the options the name, if I chose one toyota the subscribe function is firing twice. Anyone encounter this?

Comment: please share your JS code so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the "new value" you are getting on each subscribe?

You likely have an incorrect binding where it's setting the value and then setting it back to the first value in the list as the value you picked wasn't valid. This happens with dropdowns, where if you apply a new value, but it's not in the dropdown list, it will be reset back to the first value in the dropdown.

So basically, the question is are you setting it to a value that's valid in the dropdown? And is something resetting the dropdown value?